# How can i make a copy of a previous appsheet entry to expedite creating similar orders?

Tags: google-app-engine

Each order entry I'm making in appsheet for a logistics for my company has many fields. Sometimes I need to make multiple order entries which are very similar in detail initially. It's very time-consuming and repetitive to enter each one of these manually, so I'd like it if I could create one and then make copies with the same basic information. Another use would be repeating an old order.

This would save me and the other users a lot of time. Any tips on how to do this without going into the Google Sheets back-end directly?

Answer (score 0):

most AppSheet questions are asked and answered at http://community.appsheet.com

To your specific question, the ability to copy a record is not supported as of May 29th, 2017, but the featured is scheduled to be available in the first two weeks of June 2017.